# getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ResourceBundleLocator

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring configuration file like

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"  
            p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application" 
            p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />         

<beans:bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</beans:bean>

<annotation-driven validator="validator" />

<resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

<default-servlet-handler/>

...
```

When i run the code i get the error that

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with 
name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Error setting property 
values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException;
nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException:  
Property 'validationMessageSource' threw exception; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/resourceloading
/ResourceBundleLocator
```

Why i am getting this error o have bean defined with messageSource?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have hibernate-validator on your class path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incorrect version of Hibernate Validator. Spring supports **4.x**. Hibernate **5.x** will be supported in Spring 4+.

Official issue report - https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10466.

Comment: i do have hibernate-validator in my POM like this `<dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Wow... that is pretty new. I not sure Spring is compatible with version 5. That might be the issue... try downgrading to 4.x.

Comment: And here you go https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10466 . Hibernate Validator 5 will be supported in Spring 4. I will rewrite my answer.

Comment: I am suing spring 3.2.3 but version 5 isn't working. Thanks This works `<dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
         <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding this dependency to my maven pom.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

i am using spring framework 4.0.0.RELEASE